# API Gateway Cognito Authorizer Declared via Cloudformation Requires Deploy From Management Console to Work Properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-sam

I don't understand the following behavior of my API Gateway and Cognito User Pool Authorizer. Using the AWS SAM template, I have deployed the following Cognito User Pool:

```yaml
  CognitoUserPoolClient:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
    Properties:
      UserPoolId: !Ref CognitoUserPool
      ClientName: !Sub CognitoUserPoolClient-${StageName}
      GenerateSecret: false
      SupportedIdentityProviders:
        - COGNITO
      ExplicitAuthFlows:
        - ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH
        - ALLOW_CUSTOM_AUTH
        - ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH
        - ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH
  OptalXCognitoUserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
      AutoVerifiedAttributes:
        - email
      EmailVerificationSubject: Verify your email.
      EmailVerificationMessage: Please click the link below to verify your email address. {####}
      EmailConfiguration:
        EmailSendingAccount: DEVELOPER
        From: Widgets Co <admin@widgets.com>
        ReplyToEmailAddress: admin@widgets.com
        SourceArn: !FindInMap [ StageMap, !Ref StageName, EmailSESArn ]
      UserPoolName: !Sub CognitoUserPool-${StageName}
      VerificationMessageTemplate:
        DefaultEmailOption: CONFIRM_WITH_LINK
      AdminCreateUserConfig:
        AllowAdminCreateUserOnly: true
        UnusedAccountValidityDays: 90
        InviteMessageTemplate:
          EmailMessage: ...
          EmailSubject: Welcome to Widgets Co!
          SMSMessage: Your username is {username} and temporary password is {####}.
      Policies:
        PasswordPolicy:
          MinimumLength: 8
      UsernameAttributes:
        - email
      Schema:
        - AttributeDataType: String
          Name: user_id
          Mutable: false
          DeveloperOnlyAttribute: false
        - Name: email
          Mutable: false
          Required: true
```

Then, I've defined an API Gateway that uses the Cognito User Pool as its Authorizer:

```yaml
  WidgetsAPI:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Api'
    Name: WidgetsAPI
    Properties:
      GatewayResponses:
        EXPIRED_TOKEN:
          ResponseParameters:
            Headers:
              Fail-Reason: "'Expired token'"
              Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
        DEFAULT_4xx:
          ResponseParameters:
            Headers:
              Access-Control-Expose-Headers: "'WWW-Authenticate'"
              Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
        DEFAULT_5XX:
          ResponseParameters:
            Headers:
              Fail-Reason: "'Internal server error. Check logs.'"
              Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: CognitoAuthorizer
        Authorizers:
          CognitoAuthorizer:
            UserPoolArn: !FindInMap [ StageMap, !Ref StageName, UserPoolArn ]
        AddDefaultAuthorizerToCorsPreflight: false
```

Here my `UserPoolArn` is inside a `Mappings` that differs based on the environment we are in (`stage` or `prod`). I've defined a bunch of endpoints, but for the sake of demonstration, there's on called `/users`.

Now when I pass in a `GET /prod/users` request, with a header of `Authorization: THE_ID_TOKEN_FROM_MY_COGNITO_SIGN_IN`, I receive a `401 Unauthorized`. I can 100% confirm that I am using the right ID token. For instance, when I pass in the same ID token to test via the management console's authorizer screen, I get a `200` response:
[image]

Moreover, I've deployed in our company's stack multiple API endpoints, all with the same pattern - we've been using `id_token` for the past year quite successfully. The only difference is we are trying to move our managed user pools into CloudFormation templates, so the most recent User Pool (including this problematic one) were created via `aws sam build`.

Why is this happening? I know I may not have provided enough details, but happy to add any other pieces of code or configs that are relevant. It's hard for me to reproduce this error since in all my other environments (`stage`, my other microservices API endpoints), the API Gateway and Cognito User Pool work perfectly after being deployed via AWS SAM.

In fact, I've deployed the exact same version of this infrastructure in our staging environment, and it works perfectly (the only difference between our stage and prod environments is the `Stage` parameter that we pass into our template YAML stack).

I've found that if I go into the management console and manually deploy the API again, everything works great (I get a `200` response with the expected response output):
[image]

Note - there's several posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54573647/messageunauthorized-in-api-gateway-in-cognito-authorizer), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50778387/api-gateway-cognito-user-pool-authorizer-401-unauthorized?rq=1), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345005/aws-api-gateway-authorizer-cognito-user-pool-not-working-message-unauthor?rq=1)) about this topic, but none of them describe my exact problem, which is why my API Gateway returns `401 Unauthorized` errors upon first applying my Cloudformation stack, and only works properly after I manually deploy from the console the entire API Gateway stage.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment` resource to your template.

```yaml
ApiGatewayDeployment:
  DependsOn:
    - Function1Name
    - Thing2Name
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
  Properties:
    RestApiId: !Ref WidgetsAPI
    StageName: !Sub ApiGateway-${ApiGatewayStageName}
```

now `sam deploy` will have your api deploy to `"ApiGateway-loremipsum"`

Comment: thanks - I tried this but unfortunately I still run into the same issue.